# Query to split data from columns into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has true/false columns for delivery and pickup in the same row. I would like to query this data so that it returns delivery and pickup in separate rows.

Current Table:

| Order | NAME | Delvr | DeliveryDate | Pickup | PickupDate | QTY | Item Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | 1 | 7/31/2023 | 1 | 8/4/2023 | 32 | Item 1 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | 1 | 7/31/2023 | 1 | 8/4/2023 | 20 | Item 2 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | 1 | 7/31/2023 | 1 | 8/4/2023 | 5 | Item 3 |

Expected Query Result:

| Order | NAME | TripType | TripDate | QTY | Item Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | Delivery | 7/31/2023 | 32 | Item 1 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | Delivery | 7/31/2023 | 20 | Item 2 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | Delivery | 7/31/2023 | 5 | Item 3 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | Pickup | 8/4/2023 | 32 | Item 1 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | Pickup | 8/4/2023 | 20 | Item 2 |
| 198747 | Joe Dirt | Pickup | 8/4/2023 | 5 | Item 3 |

A new column would be needed called "TripType" and for every row marked true for "Delvr" or "Pickup" a new row would be made with the "TripType" of "Delivery" or "Pickup"

If the row was for a "TripType" delivery (or pickup), the "DeliveryDate" (or "PickupDate) would return in a new column called "TripDate".

Comment: Be great to see what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple solution is to UNION two separate queries - one for the delivery, one for the pickup

```
SELECT [Order], [NAME], 'Delivery' AS TripType,
DeliveryDate AS TripDate, QTY, [Item Name]
FROM [table]
WHERE Delvr = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT [Order], [NAME], 'Pickup' AS TripType,
Pickup AS TripDate, QTY, [Item Name]
FROM [table]
WHERE Pickup = 1
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. I was trying another solution that I found but I couldnt quite get it to work. Makes sense, thank you very much!